# jsoncpp find or write a value into substructure via combined keys

Tags: c++, json, key, jsoncpp

I am using the jsoncpp library to parse and create json structures. Is it possible to convert following syntax

```
    jsonText["name1"]["name2"] = "Testmessage";
```

into something like this

```
    jsonText["name1.name2"] = "Testmessage";
```

so that

```
    jsonText["name1"]["name2"] = jsonText["name1.name2"];
```

Regards

Comment: Supposed this isn't possible, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Do you want to modify the library to do this? That would be a bad idea since any legitimate `name1.name2` collides with `["name1"]["name2"]`. That said, you can do this manually. Parse it like normal and iterate through each subarray (i.e. `jsonText[key1]`) and convert all of those keys to `key1.key2` and add it to the top-level of your structure.